# div with horizontal scroll

Tags: html, scroll

With a div that is completed with a dynamically added table. The problem is the right div, it doesn't show the full table, and I can't scroll

The div code is 
    `<div style='height:460px;overflow:auto;'>`

[image: my app]

I also tried with

```
<div style='height:460px;overflow:auto;overflow-x: scroll;'>
```

but I get this

[image: my app 2]

Comment: maybeyou should apply the overflow:auto only to the <table> element, leaving its container retain its width.

Comment: @kumiau: that don't work

Comment: I've had similar issues in the past, and I think in my case the display property was messing things up. Maybe you have like a display: inline-block inherited somewhere?